# Create a folder outside Visual Studio 2013 and make VS to recognise and show it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I can't believe I'm asking this but is there any official way of:

**"Create a folder outside Visual Studio 2013 and make VS to recognise and show it"**

I worked around this through actually pasting the folder in the IDE (not cool, folder was already in the Web folder it was just not showing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, it's just easier to do it through visual studio. You'll have to open up the *.csproj file and edit it directly. Under `<ItemGroup>` you will see lines like this:

```
<Content Include="AFolderInVS\MyJavaScriptfile.js" />
```

You don't specify the folder, but all the files individually. Optionally you add all your folders and have someone with visual studio to "include" the folder. Visual studio will then add all the files in the folder automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you see inside Visual Studio solution aren't classic folders that you know. The VS "folders" are called filters and you need to create them explicitly in the solution.